# Can someone identify this classical track?

Tags: identify-this-song, classical-music, piano

could someone please identify the song from 00:13? It's a bit hard to hear because it was recorded on the airport and there is someone talking in the speaker. It's a classical track that I've heard somewhere before.

This is the link:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I actually found it: It's Chopin's *"Nadia Elle Nocturne Op.9 No1 in B Flat Minor"*

Comment: You are welcome! One can never be wrong when it's Chopin. Specifically the name of this first tune is "Nadia Elle Nocturne Op.9 No1 in B Flat Minor".

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like an instrumental version of the song "Hijo de la Luna" by the Spanish band Mecano. Here's a link https://youtu.be/OwGG5fX7bxY

Comment: Hey, no that's not it, that surely must be something more classical. Thanks anyway!